# How to find all occurrences of a pattern using std::regex_search?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I have the following code to parse a bunch of part numbers (basically serial numbers of components of a product) from an arbitrarily formatted file.

```
auto buildPartNumberRegexString( bool preFlash ) -> std::string
{
    std::ostringstream patternBuilder;

    // The original, raw literal as tested on https://regex101.com/ is:
    //
    // @@PART_NUMBER_POST_FLASH\<\s*(\S+)\s*\,\s*(\d+)\s*\>@@
    //
    // In C++, each backslash needs to be doubled. Alternatively, we could use raw string literals ( R"\w" ).

    patternBuilder << "@@PART_NUMBER_" << ( preFlash ? "PRE" : "POST" )
        << "_FLASH\\<\\s*(\\S+)\\s*\\,\\s*(\\d+)\\s*\\>@@";

    return patternBuilder.str();
}

auto parsePartNumberAddresses( const std::string& templateFileContent, bool preFlash ) -> ParamAddressContainer
{
    const std::regex regEx( buildPartNumberRegexString( preFlash ) );
    std::smatch match;

    if ( std::regex_search( templateFileContent, match, regEx ) )
    {
        assert( match.size() > 1 );
        const std::size_t capturedGroups = match.size() - 1;

        assert( capturedGroups % 2 == 0 );
        const std::size_t partNumberAddressesFound = capturedGroups / 2;

        ParamAddressContainer results;
        results.reserve( partNumberAddressesFound );

        std::cerr << "DEBUG: capturedGroups = " << capturedGroups << ", partNumberAddressesFound = " << partNumberAddressesFound
            << "\n";

        for ( std::size_t i = 0; i < partNumberAddressesFound; ++i )
        {
            const std::size_t paramIdMatchIndex = i * 2 + 1;
            const std::string paramIdString = match.str( paramIdMatchIndex );
            const std::string paramIndexString = match.str( paramIdMatchIndex + 1 );

            results.emplace_back( util::string_funcs::fromString< ParamId_t > ( paramIdString ),
                util::string_funcs::fromString< ParamIndex_t > ( paramIndexString ) );
        }

        std::cerr << "DEBUG: Going to read the following part numbers (" << ( preFlash ? "pre" : "post" ) << "-flash):\n\n";

        for ( const auto& paramAddress : results )
        {
            std::cerr << "\t" << std::hex << std::noshowbase << paramAddress.paramId << std::dec << "<" << paramAddress.paramIndex
                << ">\n";
        }

        return results;
    }

    return ParamAddressContainer();
}
```

I've written the "beautified" regex (i.e. without the double backslashes required to escape the actual backslashes) in the comment in the buildPartNumberRegexString function.

A sample file that I'm using this regex on might look like this:

```
Component alpha;@@PART_NUMBER_POST_FLASH<F12C,0>@@
Component beta;@@PART_NUMBER_POST_FLASH<F12C,1>@@
```

I've tested my regex, using that same sample file, on https://regex101.com/ and it works exactly as it should, matching both occurrences and extracting the desired match groups. The problem is that, when I try to do the same thing via std::regex it only finds the first match. Now on  https://regex101.com/ I had to enable the **g** modifier *(global, All matches, don't return on first match)* for the regex to find all matches. I'm assuming (hoping) that a similar flag is available for `std::regex_search`, but the description of the available flags (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_flag_type) doesn't seem to list any that meets my requirements. Surely there has to be a way to find more than one occurrence of a pattern, right? Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: The cppreference.com page on std::regex_iterator shows how to get all matches.. guess I should add a note to std::regex_search

Comment: Cubbi, I'm not sure it does. The example on cppreference invokes uses regex_search repeatedly on all strings in an array. In my case I don't have an array of strings, I have just a string. I know that I could split my sample file into lines, but as I said, the input could be arbitrarily formatted, and there is no guarantee I'll always have one match per line. There could 2 or more in a single line.

Comment: Yes, it wasn't obvious. Added a note.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if people feel that this doesn't warrant posting an answer to my own question, but I figured I'd post my updated and working solution for others who are also looking for a solution. Ok, following Cubbi's advice, I've decided to use std::regex_iterator, which I prefer over having to invoke std::regex_search repeatedly. Below is my revised parsePartNumberAddresses function:

```
auto parsePartNumberAddresses( const std::string& templateFileContent, bool preFlash ) -> ParamAddressContainer
{
    const std::regex regEx( buildPartNumberRegexString( preFlash ) );

    const auto begin_iterator = std::sregex_iterator( templateFileContent.cbegin(), templateFileContent.cend(), regEx );
    const auto end_iterator = std::sregex_iterator();

    ParamAddressContainer results;

    for ( std::sregex_iterator it = begin_iterator; it != end_iterator; ++it )
    {
        const std::smatch& match = *it;
        assert( match.size() == 3 );

        const std::string paramIdString = match.str( 1 );
        const std::string paramIndexString = match.str( 2 );

        results.emplace_back( util::string_funcs::fromString< ParamId_t > ( paramIdString ),
            util::string_funcs::fromString< ParamIndex_t > ( paramIndexString ) );
    }

    std::cerr << "DEBUG: Going to read the following part numbers (" << ( preFlash ? "pre" : "post" ) << "-flash):\n\n";

    for ( const auto& paramAddress : results )
    {
        std::cerr << "\t" << std::hex << std::noshowbase << paramAddress.paramId << std::dec << "<" << paramAddress.paramIndex
            << ">\n";
    }

    return results;
}
```

This works exactly as intended, giving **all** matches in the subject string. :)

**UPDATE**: As suggested by rici, removed superfluous std::distance() as well as results.reserve() calls to prevent evaluating the regex twice.

Comment: Doing the entire regex search twice just so that you can presize `results` is false economy (to say the least).

Comment: rici, I don't think I am doing it twice. Unless the regex is reevaluated each time I iterate over the results. Is that what happens?

EDIT: Quote from cppreference: On construction, and **on every increment**, it calls std::regex_search [...]

Ugh, you may be right. :-(

Comment: Just ditch the computation of `matches_found`. `emplace_back` will resize as necessary.

Comment: By the way, why do you use `util::string_funcs::fromString< ParamId_t >` instead of having an `explicit ParamId(const std::string&)` constructor? (Rhetorical question, no need to answer.)

Comment: rici, at the moment, ParamId_t is just a bare typedef for unsigned int. I might turn into a proper class later on. :)

Comment: Another design might be a `ParamAddress` constructor which takes two strings (assuming that `ParamAddressContainer` is actually `some_container<ParamAddress>`)

Comment: @rici Oh, by the way, I did know that emplace_back() will automatically resize the container. I was just trying to avoid unnecessary reallocations by using reserve() to make sure the container had the necessary capacity before putting stuff in it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't intend to imply that you didn't know that. I meant that most of the time the optimization isn't worth doing. Unless it comes absolutely for free.